# IntelliJ Spring Boot project creates inline-imports for Spring-Annotations on new .java-files

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, import

Cheers,

I am trying to learn some SpringBoot and wanted to code a simple web server. While trying to create RestController class and annotating it in a new .java File, IntelliJ decided to create an inline import for reasons only god knows.

Not working imports:

```java
package com.mystuff.inventur.rest;

@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

}
```

I'd like IntelliJ to create import statements instead of doing these funky inline package calls. Classic java classes however IntelliJ imports normally. Manually writing the @RestController and trying to import it doesn't work either since IntelliJ doesn't seem to recognize it.

Though the .java file created by the Spring Initializr seems to work perfectly fine when it comes to Spring Annotations.

Working Imports:

```java
package com.mystuff.inventur;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class InventurApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InventurApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

These are my IntelliJ-java-import-settings:
[image: java imports config]

[image: java autoimport config]

Already tried to check and uncheck the 3 checkboxes in the general section of the import tab regarding the java code settings.

Anyone encountered this problem yet and has a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Intellij is doing that because you have called your class with the same name as annotation. So in order to avoid ambiguity you have to fully qualify the import. Just rename your class

Comment: Ah damn, didn't pay attention to that. And I searched like a madman for a solution. Thank you very much, that was the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a proper answer (originally in comment from @JAsgarov):

IntelliJ is doing that because you have named your class with the same name as annotation (just a different package). So in order to avoid ambiguity you have to fully qualify the import.

Just rename your class and the annotation can be imported and used with only its name:

```java
package com.mystuff.inventur.rest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class InventurController {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your class name and the Spring annotation name are same, it needs inline imports.

```
package com.mystuff.inventur.rest;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
    @RestController public class MyRestController {
    
    }
```